# c# UWP window location on screen issue

Tags: c#, uwp, location, window, screen

How to get window absolute location on screen?

In WPF there was:

```
var location = myTextBlock.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
```

But in UWP I can't find anything similar...

Any idea on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388558/7604843  Try the answer found there.

Comment: I am getting coordinates of the control in page. I need window coordinates on Screen...

Comment: The answer is giving you page coordinates?

Comment: Are you passing the `Window` to the `TransformToVisual` call?

Comment: What does it even mean to have "absolute coordinates" on HoloLens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the Windows position on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082799/how-can-i-set-the-windows-position-on-startup)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assuming ctl is the control whose absolute screen coordinates you seek:

```
Dim ttv As GeneralTransform = ctl.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content)
Dim WindowCoords As Point = ttv.TransformPoint(New Point(0, 0))
Dim ScreenCoordsX as double = WindowsCoords.X + ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Left
Dim ScreenCoordsY as double = WindowsCoords.Y + ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Top
```

You can add ctl.ActualWidth to find the right hand side, but if you've applied a ScaleTransform to the control, you'll have to multiply ActualWidth by that same scale, as ActualWidth isn't affected by transforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get nor set the window's location on the screen in the current UWP API. You can only partially control its size.

You can use the `AdjacentToLeftDisplayEdge` and `AdjacentToRightDisplayEdge` to query if the window is snapped to a side of the screen. You can also use `IsFullScreenMode` property to query whether the app is full screen.

Comment: You can get it.  Use: ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds

You just can't set it.